# How to build the tree grid in UI from XML file as data source?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to build the tree grid by parsing XML file.

I saw **[extJS XML TREE](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-xml)** example but it require to have specific tags in XML file like id (to describe parent - child relationship), text (to print the tree node Name) , and leaf (to specify leaf and non leaf element) tags.

So, I have to manipulate my xml file to add these tags. But, is there any way i can achieve same result without adding extra tags?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want your own custom reader. You can use a custom reader to intercept your xml response and modify it before it goes into your store. For example, loading the following xml file will result in a grid where the first "foo" value is 11 :

```
Ext.define('MyReader', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.reader.Xml',
    alias : 'reader.myreader',
    getResponseData: function(response) {
        // Here is the xmlDocument you are going to change
        var xmlDoc = response.responseXML;

        // I change the first foo value to 11.
        var fooValues=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('foo');
        fooValues[0].innerHTML=11;

        return this.callParent([response]);
    }
});

Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Foo', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype  : 'fiddle-foo',

    store: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['foo'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data1.xml',
            reader: {
                type  : 'myreader', // instead of xml
                root  : 'root',
                record: 'fooRecord'
            }
        }    
    },

    columns : [
        {
            text      : 'Foo',
            dataIndex : 'foo',
            flex      : 1
        }
    ]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        new Fiddle.view.Foo({
            renderTo : document.body,
            width    : 400,
            height   : 400,
            title    : 'Test'
        });
    }
});
```

You can check this out on sencha fiddle with this sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <fooRecord>
        <foo>1</foo>
    </fooRecord>
    <fooRecord>
        <foo>2</foo>
    </fooRecord>
</root>
```

I understand you probably can't switch from XML to JSON since your not touching the server at all, but JSON is much simpler to parse if you are able to. You can find similar steps for that here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261182-How-to-implement-custom-JSON-reader

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can able to load my xml file data in grid panel but when i try to load it in tree panel it requires additional tags in xml file like leaf tag(to know leaf node), id tag (to know the hierarchy). So, could you suggest me an approach where i dont need to add those extra tags and still i can load my xml file data in tree panel?

Comment: Unfortunately, those fields are necessary if you want to use a treepanel. If you don't want to add them in as appropriate using the reader, another option is to use a [dataview](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.View). You would use an [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) to create your HTML markup. You don't get quite as many freebies with some events/features built-in, but it gives you way more freedom for your server side.